# make btn color to btn-info in toggled navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want btn in navbar (which appeared only toggled) get btn-info color.
I add a btn-info class,

btn's text color changed to white

and btn color was unchanged.

I used default bootstrap 3 css.

[bootply - click mobile view](http://www.bootply.com/104506)

```
    <a class="btn btn-info navbar-toggle" value="Page" href="javascript:win_memo('', '<?=$member[mb_id]?>', '<?=$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]?>');" onfocus="this.blur()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"><sup style="margin-left:3px;"><?=$member[mb_memo_unread]?></sup></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo in http://bootply.com

Comment: @Surjith// I add a bootply. 2nd btn (memo) is btn-info. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use ( `!important` ) for your btn-info property value, because the (`.btn-info`) 
is overridden by the (`.navbar-toggle`) class value, so the solution is to add this code to your **custome.css** file or ***any file that you use to override the main bootstrap.css*** file.

***code:***

```
.btn-info {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #5bc0de !important;
 border-color: #46b8da !important;
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed Na's Answer works well. Great idea.

I add a class btn-info-navbar.

```
.btn-info-navbar {
color: #fff;
background-color: #5bc0de !important;
border-color: #46b8da !important;
}
```

and add btn-info-navbar.

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-info-navbar navbar-toggle" value="Page" href="javascript:win_memo('', '<?=$member[mb_id]?>', '<?=$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]?>');" onfocus="this.blur()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"><sup style="margin-left:3px;"><?=$member[mb_memo_unread]?></sup></i>
</a>
```